# Objective C - Difference between return NSObject and return objc_getAssociatedObject()

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I have the next code:

```
// UITextField+Navigation.h
@interface UITextField (Navigation)

@property (weak, nonatomic) UIControl *nextUIControl;

@end

//UITextField+Navigation.m
@implementation UITextField (Navigation)

- (UIControl *) nextUIControl {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &defaultHashKey);
}

- (void) setNextUIControl:(UIControl *)nextUIControl {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &defaultHashKey, nextUIControl, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

What's the difference between:

```
return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &defaultHashKey);
```

and

```
return self.nextUIControl;
```

I tried both ways, and the second one enter in a infinity loop... why?? maybe it's a obvious answer but I'm a beginner developer ^^'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this return statement being written?

Comment: @Chuck I assume he means inside the `nextUIControl` method.

Comment: Try `self ->nextUIControl` (or `self ->_nextUIControl`, depending on how your properties are synthesized).

Comment: @HotLicks Notice this is a category. Accessing `->_nextUIControl` would result in a bad access.

Comment: Yep, in a category you're kinda SOL.

Comment: @Chuck replace the "return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &defaultHashKey);" statement with "return self.nextUIControl;" like Leo Natan says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you must know than when you write

`self.nextUIControl`

it actually is compiled in

'return [self nextUIControl]'

The dotSyntax in objective-C is not to access the local variable like in java but to provide a more readable syntax to call the getters and setters.

So, in a getter for the property variable, you should not return self.variable, cause that would be an infinite loop.

If you want to return the local variable, you can't write _nextUIControl (this is your private local variable automatically generated by the property).
However, here in this scenario, you are in a objective-C categorie, and, because of the 'protected' visibility doesn't exist in objective-C, the category cannot access directly _nextUIControl, so one has to use the syntaxe objc-get / objc-set to get and set the value for the object at the address &defaulthashkey.

Answer (score 5):

`self.nextUIControl` is the dot notation for `[self nextUIControl]`. So what happens, in fact, is you are calling an endless recursion.

Your code demonstrates a property defined in a class category. Since categories cannot introduce additional instance variables, associated objects are used for both setting and getting.

Comment: So... in objc_getAssociatedObject() and objc_setAssociatedObject are where every getter and setter "land"??

Comment: @Soto_iGhost No. They land in your case. Normally, when a property is defined in a class in its main implementation, there is an instance variable (aka `_propertyName`) and that is where the value is stored. But since this is a class category, the object has to be kept in an external storage, which is what the association model is.